# "Favorite" vs. "favourite"

Tags: orthography, o-ou

Excuse my stupid question, but do "favorite" and "favourite" mean the same thing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They have the same meaning, but **favourite** is used in British English, Australian English, New Zealand English and Canadian English whereas **favorite** is used in American English.

Answer (score 17):

It's not a stupid question. No single person knows everything.

The "ou" is a common British spelling, whereas in American English, we simply use the "o." For example:

- favourite vs. favorite
- colour vs. color
- labour vs. labor
- honour vs. honor

..and so on.

Comment: +1. For further reading, see [American and British English spelling differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences) on Wikipedia.

Comment: if colour and color are the same then, why is it so, that when we are designing a webpage on NotePad, the web browser (could be any) does not accept 'bgcolour'?

Comment: Because Tim Berners Lee wanted to separate content from form?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they mean the same thing. From Wiktionary's entry on *[favorite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/favorite)*:

> English
>
> Alternative forms
>
> - (Commonwealth English) favourite

Answer (score 1):

They are two different spellings for the same word: favorite is used in American English, favourite in all other varieties of English.

The same also goes for words such as behaviour/behavior, colour/color, etc. 
In these case, the -u- can be left out because it's silent, the same however cannot be said for other words like pour and devour, which do not become por and devor, because spelling them like this would also alter their pronunciation.